# powershell in bat (мультистрочный код как одна строка)

Tags: bat, powershell

Есть рабочий батник с *powershell*-кодом в одну строку:

```
powershell -Command "& {$cont = wget http://САЙТ.info/; $cont = 
$cont.Content; $FilePath = 'contentFronHtml.txt' -f $env:SystemDrive; $cont 
| Out-File -FilePath $FilePath -Append -Width 200;}"
```

Я же хочу разбить *powershell*-код, чтобы получилось что-то наподобие:

```
SET LONG_COMMAND="$cont = wget http://САЙТ.info/;"
"$cont = $cont.Content;"
"$FilePath = 'contentFronHtml.txt' -f $env:SystemDrive;$cont | Out-File -
FilePath; $FilePath -Append -Width 200;"
powershell -Command "& {LONG_COMMAND}"
```

Как соединить строки *powershell*-кода?

Comment: Почему бы вам не сделать сразу powershell-скрипт вместо батника?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ответ получил на английском SO

This is how I would expect to do this sort of thing:

```
PowerShell -Command "first line up to the end of a command;"^
"next line up to the end of a command;"^
"another line up to the end of a command;"^
"last line"
```

You could also try this idea too:

```
Set "MyCmnd=first line up to the end of a command;"
Set "MyCmnd=%MyCmnd% next line up to the end of a command;"
Set "MyCmnd=%MyCmnd% another line up to the end of a command;"
Set "MyCmnd=%MyCmnd% last line"
Echo %MyCmnd%
```